# All in one calendar month view previews don't hide

Tags: wordpress

I am using the all in one calendar.
When I am in month view I can hover over items to get a preview of the event details. When I move my mouse away, or hit esc, or click away, no matter what I try, the preview remains.

This is annoying since the preview can cover up other days.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's a screenshot.
Note how the previews are all expanded and they don't go back .

**[UPDATE]**
If you need to view it you can go to [timetolaugh.ca](http://timetolaugh.ca/?page_id=10)
The issue occurs in Chrome, FF, and IE.
Thanks for the help so far. I've inquired on the theme custom script [here on the theme support page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-script-missing?replies=1)

[image]

Comment: Looking at Firefox's Web Developer console, I get the following whenever I mouseout from the event's link:  `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .ai1ec-event-container.ai1ec-event-id-32.ai1ec-event-instance-id-5. .ai1ec-event-popup @ http://timetolaugh.ca/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:3`

Comment: Also, on loading the page, I get `[09:51:17.125] TypeError: c is null @ http://timetolaugh.ca/wp-content/themes-ai1ec/vortex/js/calendar.min.js?ver=1.10.5-8:1` in the console.

Comment: **You must troubleshoot** to make sure where the issue is comming from: disable all other plugins and swap to a default theme. Does it still happens?

Comment: Check to make sure that all your themes scripts are loading correctly.  On page load I got a 404 for one of the theme's custom script files which could be causing the issue with all the other errors from jQuery mentioned by Pat J (I also got the same errors as Pat): Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://timetolaugh.ca/wp-content/themes/point/js/customscript.js?ver=3.8  PS: glad to see you are using 3.8 :)

Comment: @htech That could well be the answer.  I didn't try clicking through to all the JS scripts.  I'd say add it as an answer, and let the OP decide if it's the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Pat_J's suggestion I have moved this from a comment to a potential answer.

Check to make sure that all your themes scripts are loading correctly. On page load I got a `404` error for one of the theme's custom script files (`customscript.js`) which could be causing the issue with all the other errors from jQuery mentioned by Pat J (I also got the same errors as Pat):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://timetolaugh.ca/wp-content/themes/point/js/customscript.js?ver=3.8
```

I looked your theme up on wordpress.org and found it.  Here is the file for **v1.0.6** of the **Point** theme. Change the version number in the url below if you know you aren't running the latest version of the theme.

http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/point/1.0.6/js/customscript.js

Save the file to your downloads folder (just ctrl+s in your browser) then upload it using an FTP client to your host in the `/wp-content/themes/point/js/` folder.  Backup any existing version of the `customscript.js` file that is on the server (might be a permissions issue which should be fixed by uploading)

**LAST RESORT**

If you are sure that it isn't a problem with page loading then I would build a jQuery script similar to the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".ai1ec-event-popup").on('mouseleave', function () {
        jQuery(this).fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

But **please** try to fix the page loading before patching with a script.